# How to keep the index in a React.useState?

Tags: reactjs

I have an index on my map function on the `image` and I want to keep that in a `useState` `const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState()` because I want to use it for a ternary operator. But how do i do that?

Comment: on which condition you want to set ```selectedIndex```?

Answer (score 1):

I think best thing you could do is

```
// keep a state for the selected items, it's null initially
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState(null);


<li ref={itemRef}
    ....
    onMouseEnter={() => { handleMouseEnter(index, item) }}//pass the items to the function

function handleMouseLeave() {
    .....
    setSelectedItem(null)// set selected item to null on mouse leave
}


function handleMouseEnter(index, item) {
  setMouseLeave(true)
  setSelectedItem(item)
}


selectedItem && <animated.img
        key={selectedItem .id}
        style={animatedProps}
        className={styles.image}
        src={selectedItem.coverImageDefault}
        srcSet={selectedItem.coverImage}
      />
```

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dvqzq9) a simplified version for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is now that it shows both images. But the intention is to show only the image that is a match with the item. Can you help me with that? I have updated my code

Comment: Yeeeaah i know but something is wrong with mine. Because at mine it shows both images on every hover. Do you know why that is?